# Nested sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have an array, which I want to be sort in an order so that items should be in order of group and nested groups.

`groupItem` is the array which needs to be sorted in a way to achieve the supposed output.

**Given Array :**

```
var groupItem = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    groupItem.push({ "Group": "Group1", "Item1": i, "Item2": "Item " + i, "GroupId" : 1 });
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    groupItem.push({ "Group": "Group2", "Item1": i, "Item2": "Item " + i, "GroupId": 2, "Parent Group": null });
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    groupItem.push({ "Group": "Item 2", "Item1": i, "Item2": "Item " + i, "GroupId": 3, "Parent Group": 1 });
}
```

**Supposed output :**

```
[
{ "Group": "Group1", "Item1": 1, "Item2": "Item 1", "GroupId" : 1, "Parent Group": null },
{ "Group": "Group1", "Item1": 2, "Item2": "Item 2", "GroupId" : 1, "Parent Group": null },
{ "Group": "Item 2", "Item1": 1, "Item2": "Item 1", "GroupId" : 3, "Parent Group": 1 },
{ "Group": "Item 2", "Item1": 2, "Item2": "Item 2", "GroupId" : 3, "Parent Group": 1 },
{ "Group": "Group1", "Item1": 3, "Item2": "Item 3", "GroupId" : 1, "Parent Group": null },
{ "Group": "Group2", "Item1": 1, "Item2": "Item 1", "GroupId" : 2, "Parent Group": null},
{ "Group": "Group2", "Item1": 2, "Item2": "Item 2", "GroupId" : 2, "Parent Group": null }
]
```

Comment: Please share your code as well

Comment: updated, i remove error

Comment: How is the order of the parent groups defined? For example there are two items with `Group1` - how would you know which is first?

Comment: if "Parent Group" is missing it can be treated as null.., sorry I forgot to mention it..

Comment: how do you know, that both `"Parent Group": 1` go to the second one of `GroupId : 1`? ther is no identifier which helps to group this items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic here is initially tricky but it can be simplified when you look into it.

In essence, the ordering is by `GroupId`, so you get: `GroupId: 1` -> `GroupId: 2` -> `GroupId: 3`, etc.

However, if an item has a `Parent Group` property, then *that* acts as their `GroupId` for sorting: `GroupId: 1` -> `Parent Group: 1` -> `GroupId: 2` etc.

```js
var groupItem = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    groupItem.push({ "Group": "Group1", "Item1": i, "Item2": "Item " + i, "GroupId" : 1 });
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    groupItem.push({ "Group": "Group2", "Item1": i, "Item2": "Item " + i, "GroupId": 2, "Parent Group": null });
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    groupItem.push({ "Group": "Item 2", "Item1": i, "Item2": "Item " + i, "GroupId": 3, "Parent Group": 1 });
}

groupItem.sort((a, b) => {
  // if one item is a child of the other, then sort the parent 
  // before the item or the item after the parent
  if (a["Parent Group"] === b.GroupId) return 1;
  if (b["Parent Group"] === a.GroupId) return -1;
  
  //finally, if at least one item is not a parent group and the other 
  //or the two aren't direct parent and child of each other, then 
  //sort them by the GroupId (for parent groups) or Parent Group (for child items)
  var sortingIdA = a["Parent Group"] || a.GroupId;
  var sortingIdB = b["Parent Group"] || b.GroupId;
  
  return sortingIdA - sortingIdB;
})

console.log(groupItem);
```

Comment: your solution have `4` cycles and my only 2, and `push` operations have weight for CPU

Comment: @VadimHulevich solution is also incorrect...

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [
    { "Group": "Group1", "Item1": 1, "Item2": "Item 1", "GroupId": 1, "Parent Group": null },
    { "Group": "Group1", "Item1": 2, "Item2": "Item 2", "GroupId": 1, "Parent Group": null },
    { "Group": "Item 2", "Item1": 1, "Item2": "Item 1", "GroupId": 3, "Parent Group": 2 },
    { "Group": "Item 2", "Item1": 2, "Item2": "Item 2", "GroupId": 3, "Parent Group": 1 },
    { "Group": "Group1", "Item1": 3, "Item2": "Item 3", "GroupId": 1, "Parent Group": null },
    { "Group": "Group2", "Item1": 1, "Item2": "Item 1", "GroupId": 2, "Parent Group": null },
    { "Group": "Group2", "Item1": 2, "Item2": "Item 2", "GroupId": 2, "Parent Group": null }
]

const sorted = arr.sort((el1,el2)=>{

  if(el1["Parent Group"] && !el2["Parent Group"]){
    return -1;
  }

  if(!el1["Parent Group"] && el2["Parent Group"]){
    return 1;
  }

  if(el1["Parent Group"] && el2["Parent Group"]){
    return el1["Parent Group"]- el2["Parent Group"];
  }

  if(!el1["Parent Group"] && !el2["Parent Group"]){
    return -1;
  }

});

const sortedElse = sorted.sort((el1,el2)=>{

  if(el1["Parent Group"] || el2["Parent Group"]){
    return 0;
  }     

  return el1.Group.localeCompare(el2.Group);

});

console.log('@>sortedElse',sortedElse)
```

Comment: updated, i remove error

Comment: thanks @Vadim, but I want the array to be sorted by property Group as well, the array you picked is desired output, actual array is created using loops..

Comment: there should be some condition for "Parent Group" and "GroupId"..

Comment: @SunilChaudhary updated for property Group

Comment: i know @Vadim i have already sorted for that, but I am not getting desired output which will use both  "Parent Group" and "GroupId"...

Comment: `will use both` - What this mean @SunilChaudhary ?

Comment: @VadimHulevich child groups should be sorted *after* parent groups. Child groups have a `Parent Group` equal to `GroupId` of the parent.

Comment: you are right @VLAZ,..

Comment: Done @SunilChaudhary

Comment: This updated code returns `Group: Item2` in the beginning, it's not after `Group: Group1`.

Comment: @VLAZ `Parent Group` it's more important then just `Group`

Comment: Correct, but the *parent group* should be first as per OP's expected output, followed by all the items that belong to that group and `Group: Item 2` are children of `Group: Group1`